# How to set the ServiceHostingEnvironmentSection.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled by code in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two question:

1. I have a wcf service hosted in a console application, if i set the **ServiceHostingEnvironmentSection.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled** to true, can i access **HttpContext.Current.Session** in the console application.
2. If I can access the **HttpContext.Current.Session** in the console application, how to set the **ServiceHostingEnvironmentSection.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled** by code.

Note that I am using the **WSHttpBinding**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, and put forward in the simplest form:

- no and,
- no, you can't.

To elaborate a little, the `ServiceHostingEnvironment` class contains the  `AspNetCompatibilityEnabled` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostingenvironment.aspx) for details) and is only gettable, not settable.

This would lead one to assume - quite reliably - that you simply can't do it this way. Some guru may be aware of another method, however, I highly doubt it since this is a configuration that I think would need to be evaluated on execution of the application on the server and not during execution.

Compilation (by means of decorating elements with the `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` attribute) can also be used to configure types; but this may well go hand-in-hand with a present config file setting.

For some further reading, check out [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx).

Comment: mmmm, can i set a variable in the web application and read it in the wcf service taking into consideration that I have multiple calls to the service from different clients.

Comment: In what context? You could create an instance of the web application types required in your service but that would mean a new variable - not really helpful at all. Otherwise you could expose a web-method to deliver the variable value to authenticated callers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.

The `AspNetCompatibilityEnabled` setting would let you access the http context of the *current* application if it is an http wcf web service *hosted within IIS*. Yours isn't hosted within IIS, as it is a console application.

I don't think it really makes any sense to be able to reach `HttpContext.Current.Session` in a console application (as far as I can see, anyway). Whose session (or context) are you trying to reach? You server may have many web sites on it, each of which would have its own context. You console application is not actually related to any of these.

More can be read about this setting about half way down [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) page.